# Location of YouTrack "Time Tracking Settings"

Tags: youtrack

I want to tell YouTrack about the number of hours in a working day and I've found [this](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/YTD65/System-wide+Time+Tracking+Settings).

But I'm completely unable to reach such a page though the UI.  I see I can PUT such info, but I've no wish to go there.  My project Dashboard looks nothing like the one in those docs

I've googled my heart out looking for an answer, and I've clicked everything in sight inside YouTrack ... with no success.  Any feedback much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my "Administration", "Help" and "Services" icons are all invisible on my dashboard!  But hover the mouse over them and the mouse icon changes and the hover-over text appears!

Once I click on the invisible "Administration" icon I see "Project-Related Settings / Time Tracking" and all is good

Comment: this a actually a bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-33576. As far as I known latest YouTrack versions have it fixed.